# When does JavaScript `await` actually wait?

Tags: javascript

I was reading [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/async-functions#careful_avoid_going_too_sequential), and wondering why in the first snippet the seconde `wait()` waits the first `wait()` to finish whereas in the seconde snippet two `wait()` run async?

```
async function series() {
  await wait(500);
  await wait(500);
  return "done!";
}

async function parallel() {
  const wait1 = wait(500);
  const wait2 = wait(500);
  await wait1;
  await wait2;
  return "done!";
}

function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
}
```

Comment: You start the wait() when you call it. In the "series" you call it and await it, then call it and await it again. In the "parallel" you call two wait() at once, and THEN you await them. So they both started at the same time.

Comment: @korven shouldn't `const wait1 = wait(500);` already start this `setTimeout ` before `const wait2 = wait(500); ` gets execute?

Comment: Why I never get "done!" logged to Firefox console while executing `series()` or `parallel()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your first function:

```
async function series() {
    await wait(500); // 1
    await wait(500); // 2
    return "done!";
}
```

You're telling JS to await the first `wait` as soon as it's started.
This means the second `wait(500)` can't start, before the first one finishes:

1. Trigger `wait(500) // 1`
2. wait for that to pass
3. Trigger `wait(500) // 2`
4. wait for that to pass

In the second function:

```
async function parallel() {
    const wait1 = wait(500); // 1
    const wait2 = wait(500); // 2
    await wait1;
    await wait2;
    return "done!";
}
```

Both `wait` calls are *started*, before the code is told to await the results.

1. Trigger `wait(500) // 1`
2. Trigger `wait(500) // 2`
3. Wait for `wait1` to pass,
4. wait for `wait2` to pass

Because `wait1` and `wait2` are triggered immediately after each other, they're practically running in parallel.

Imagine this:

If 2 people both start a stopwatch at the same time, if you need to wait before each stopwatch reaches 10 seconds, you still only have to wait 10 seconds.
In the `series` function, on the other hand, the second stopwatch can't start before the first one finishes.

Comment: shouldn't const wait1 = wait(500); already start this setTimeout before const wait2 = wait(500); gets execute?

Comment: @Blake: _Start_, yes. First, `wait1` is started, but it doesn't wait for `wait1` to finish, before _starting_ `wait2`, in `parallel`

Comment: thanks! just rechecked the `setTimeout ` definition, seems i have mix it with settimeinterval..

Comment: You're welcome, @Blake. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score -2):

It depends upon async tasks if two tasks are dependent than we have to execute them in order. I.e. wait for the first task to complete; same thing is happening in first snippet that's why it taking approx 1000ms to complete.

But if two tasks are independent we can can run them parallel and await those tasks before dependent task. I.e. in case of second snippet we may need result of both tasks and then manipulate these results. That's why we are awaiting before return statement.

Its similar to C# async-await mechanism. For reference please visit [Asynchronous Programming with async and await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

Comment: Why are you linking to C# documentation?

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm linking to C# documentation just for the sake of concept as it has similar mechanism for async await.

Comment: @Cerbrus If you compare concept part of my answer with your answer it's conveying same meaning. I don't understand why my answer is being down-voted.

Comment: Zeshan, the concept is similar in C#, but the syntax is completely different.

Comment: @Cerbrus exactly! and question is not related to syntax its related concept.